# Is there any way to get around the CORS issue to get data from another website

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a website for a sporting association and they want to be able to "get" updated information from another website programatically to display on their own pages. I have attempted to do this via an AJAX call but I have come across the CORS issue as I see a lot of discussions about this, including updating allowed headers on the server etc.

I do not have any access what so ever to either server so I cannot do anything relating to updating allowed headers or anything else for that matter which requires a server side solution.

I only have client side facilities available to me (Javascript and associated frameworks/plugins like jQuery/Angular etc).

Is there a solution available that I could use to help me with this or am I completely without options given this all has to happen on the client side?

Comment: Can try a third party proxy service such as Yahoo YQL

Comment: CORS is not an **issue**, it is a **security measure**.  With that in mind, if there were a way around it, then it wouldn't really be doing it's job.

Comment: Some sites have APIs that allow access to their services paid and/or free.

Comment: If you are updating the sporting website, it logically follows that you have some access to server side technology.  Unless you ask your users to explicitly load the web browser with web security disabled (not likely) then the only option to bypass CORS is to fetch the data from the server and either inject or proxy to the web page.

Comment: @CaptEmulation, I do not have access to the server. This is a hosted CMS solution. No server access. Client side scripting is the only option available to me.

Comment: What about an intermediary server on the cloud that you set up?  Your server can disable CORS headers but still connect to the target site (because it won't be a browser)